# How I can create large file with cordova?

Tags: android, file, cordova, ionic-framework, blob

For example, I want create a file with 10mb size, so for this i used [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), but it only work with small size because `Blob` [have own limitations](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/224e43ce1ca4f6ca6f2cd8d677b8684f4b7c2351/storage/browser/blob/README.md).

So, how I can create a file with 1gb, 2gb, 3gb, ...?

My example code(this work's with small size[<7mb]):

```
export interface FileInfo {
    size : number,
    path : string,
    filename : string,
    fullpath:string
}

let random : string = 'tmp-' + (Math.random().toString(36).substring(7).toString());
let tmpFile : FileInfo = {
    size    : 10000000, // 10mb
    path    : cordova.file.dataDirectory,
    filename: random,
    fullpath: (cordova.file.dataDirectory +  '/' + random).replace(/\/+/g, '/')
};

let blob:Blob = new Blob(<any>(new Uint8Array(tmpFile.size)), {
    type:'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
});
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(tmpFile.path).then((directory:DirectoryEntry) => {
    directory.getFile(tmpFile.filename, {
        create:true
    }, (file:FileEntry) => {
        file.createWriter((writer:FileWriter) => {
            writer.seek(writer.length);
            writer.write(blob);
            file.file((info:any) => {
                console.log(tmpFile)
            }, (err:FileError) => {
                console.error(err)
            })
        }, (err:FileError) => {
            console.error(err)
        })
    }, (err:FileError) => {
        console.error(err)
    })
}, (err:any) => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

P.S: I'm using Ionic 3 with TypeScript(obviously).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?